# How do I print the variance of an lm in R without computing from the Standard Error by hand?

Tags: r, regression, variance

Simple question really!  I am running lots of linear regressions of `y~x` and want to obtain the variance for each regression without computing it from hand from the Standard Error output given in the `summary.lm` command.  Just to save a bit of time :-).  Any ideas of the command to do this?  Or will I have to write a function to do it myself?

```
m<-lm(Alopecurus.geniculatus~Year)
> summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = Alopecurus.geniculatus ~ Year)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-19.374  -8.667  -2.094   9.601  21.832 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 700.3921   302.2936   2.317   0.0275 *
Year         -0.2757     0.1530  -1.802   0.0817 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 11.45 on 30 degrees of freedom
  (15 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared: 0.09762,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.06754 
F-statistic: 3.246 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 0.08168
```

So I get a Standard Error output and I was hoping to get a Variance output without calculating it by hand...

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Just added in the example - hope it helps... :)

Comment: Sorry it was off topic - haven't used this site before :).  I mean the actual variance statistic that is in turn used to calculate the SE and so on.  It's easy to calculate, I just wondered if there was a simple call for it.  I'll do it by hand though, no matter. Cheers :)

Comment: @Sarah welcome to CV - off topic doesn't mean you won't get an answer!  Far from it - watch this space and this well get migrated to SO once enough mods have voted on it.  There are an enormous number of R experts over there that will probably know exactly what call to make.  CV would have been the place to ask the opposite question: "How do I calculate this by hand".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want the variance of.

If you want the *residual* variance, it's: `(summary(m)$sigma)**2`.

If you want the variance of your *slope*, it's: `(summary(m)$coefficients[2,2])**2`, or `vcov(m)[2,2]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  It was the variance of the slope I wanted, so that's really helpful gung, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

`vcov(m)`

gives the covariance matrix of the coefficients – variances on the diagonal.

Answer (score 11):

if you're referring to the standard errors for the coefficient estimates, the answer is

```
summary(m)$coef[,2]
```

and if you're referring to the estimated residual variance, it's

```
summary(m)$sigma
```

Type `names( summary(m) )` and `names(m)` for other information you can access.

Comment: Isn't the estimated residual variance `summary(m)$sigma^2`?