# How can I calculate the variance of coefficient in linear model using R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm quite a beginner in the field of statistics and programming languages. I've been working on my homework about multiple linear regression and I can't figure it out.

The problem is to calculate the variance of coefficients in multiple linear regression model `(Var(b0), Var(b1), ...)`. When I apply summary function to the linear model object, all I can see is standard error of each coefficients. As far as I understood, standard error is different from standard deviation and variance.

Could the standard errors possibly mean the standard deviation of coefficients in this context, or should I use other functions to calculate the SD and Var of coefficients?

```
x1 <- c(195,179,205,204,201,184,210,209)
x2 <- c(57,61,60,62,61,54,58,61)
y <- c(81.4,122.0,101.7,175.6,150.3, 64.8, 92.1,113.8)

data <- data.frame("temp"=x1,"pressure"=x2,"strength"=y)
lm.str <- lm(strength ~ temp + pressure, data=data)
summary(lm.str)
```

[image]

Comment: vcov(lm.str) might be what you want

Comment: I think your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14960868/6288065

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! problem solved!